# SQL Error "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a sub query."

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I am executing this query in Oracle. I have added the screenshots of my data and the returned results but the returned result is wrong. It is returning 1 but it should return 0.52. Because the customer(see in attached screenshot) have codes 1,2,4,31 and for 1,2,4 he should get 0.70 value and for 31 he should get 0.75 and then after multiplication the returned result should be 0.52 instead of 1. 
I am really stuck here. Please help me. I will be very thankful to you.

Here is my query. What I actually want to do is I want to calculate points value given to every customer on the basis of codes they got.

If a customer have code = 1 then he will get 0.70 points and then if he have code = 2 and 4 too then I do not want to give him extra 0.70 for code 2 and 4.

Let me be simple. If a customer have all of these codes 1, 2, 4 then he will only get 0.70 points for once, but if he have code 4 only then he will get 0.90,  but if he got code 31 too then he will get extra 0.75 for having code 31. Does it make sense now?

```
       SELECT 
       RM_LIVE.EMPLOYEE.EMPNO, RM_LIVE.EMPNAME.FIRSTNAME,
       RM_LIVE.EMPNAME.LASTNAME, RM_LIVE.CRWBASE.BASE ,RM_LIVE.CRWCAT.crwcat AS "Rank",
       nvl(nullif(MAX(CASE WHEN RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC IN (29,721) THEN 0.25 ELSE 1 END),0),1) *
       nvl(nullif(MAX(CASE WHEN RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC IN (31,723) THEN 0.75 ELSE 1 END),0),1) *
       nvl(nullif(MAX(CASE WHEN RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC = 861 THEN 0.80 ELSE 1 END),0),1) *
       nvl(nullif(MAX(CASE WHEN RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC IN (17,302,16) THEN 0.85 ELSE 1 END),0),1) *
       nvl(nullif(MAX(CASE WHEN RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC IN (3,7) THEN 0.90 ELSE 1 END),0),1)*
       nvl(nullif(MAX(CASE WHEN RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC IN (921,301,30,722,601,581) THEN 0.50 ELSE 1 END),0),1) *
       nvl(nullif(MAX(CASE WHEN RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC IN (2,1, 4) THEN 0.70 ELSE 1 END),0),1) *
       nvl(nullif(MIN(CASE WHEN RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC  IN (1,2) then 0 else 1 END) * 
                  MAX(CASE WHEN RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC  IN (4) then 0.20 else 0 END),0),1) AS "FTE VALUE"

     FROM RM_LIVE.EMPBASE,
     RM_LIVE.EMPLOYEE,
     RM_LIVE.CRWBASE,
     RM_LIVE.EMPNAME,
     RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC,
     RM_LIVE.EMPSPECFUNC,RM_LIVE.EMPQUALCAT,RM_LIVE.CRWCAT
       where RM_LIVE.EMPBASE.IDEMPNO = RM_LIVE.EMPLOYEE.IDEMPNO
        AND RM_LIVE.EMPBASE.IDCRWBASE = RM_LIVE.CRWBASE.IDCRWBASE
         AND RM_LIVE.EMPLOYEE.IDEMPNO = RM_LIVE.EMPNAME.IDEMPNO 
          AND RM_LIVE.EMPSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC =RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC  
           AND RM_LIVE.EMPSPECFUNC.IDEMPNO =RM_LIVE.EMPLOYEE.IDEMPNO
            AND  RM_LIVE.EMPQUALCAT.IDEMPNO=RM_LIVE.EMPLOYEE.IDEMPNO 
             AND  RM_LIVE.CRWCAT.IDCRWCAT = RM_LIVE.EMPQUALCAT.IDCRWCAT
              AND RM_LIVE.CRWCAT.crwcat IN ('CP','FO','CM','MC')
               AND RM_LIVE.CRWBASE.BASE <> 'XYZ'
                AND RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC IN  
                ('921','2' ,'1','301','17','4','3','7','302' ,'861','31',
                 '723','30','722 ','29 ','721','16','601','581')  
                  AND RM_LIVE.EMPBASE.STARTDATE <= SYSDATE
                   AND RM_LIVE.EMPBASE.ENDDATE >= SYSDATE
                    AND RM_LIVE.EMPSPECFUNC.STARTDATE <= SYSDATE
                     AND RM_LIVE.EMPSPECFUNC.ENDDATE >= SYSDATE
                      AND RM_LIVE.EMPNAME.FROMDATE <=SYSDATE
                       AND RM_LIVE.EMPQUALCAT.STARTDATE <= SYSDATE
                        AND RM_LIVE.EMPQUALCAT.ENDDATE >= SYSDATE
       GROUP BY RM_LIVE.EMPLOYEE.EMPNO, RM_LIVE.EMPNAME.FIRSTNAME,
       RM_LIVE.EMPNAME.LASTNAME, RM_LIVE.CRWBASE.BASE,RM_LIVE.CRWCAT.crwcat;
```

[image: My data]
[image: Returned results]

Comment: "giving error": what kind of error? Also fix your title to be more specific.

Comment: Can you add the error message?

Comment: What kind of error ?

Comment: keep comma next to name

Comment: Now after adding the comma, that error is gone but now facing another error (Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.).

Comment: I`ll edit my answer a bit later,so what should be the results for that sample data?

Comment: Add desired result for the sample data.

Comment: @Mihai I have changed the query and have added the screenshot of my data. Results should be like this. Customer with id = 1 and name = ali will get total 180 points(100 for having all codes(1,2,4) and 80 for having code = 8 ) Other two customers with id = 2 and id = 3 will get 100, 100 points

Comment: is the name the same for one id?Why 80  for code code 8?Put the logic in your question,comments are hard to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to desired reasult comment, try this

```
SELECT [id]
  ,[name]
  , r = max(CASE WHEN [code]  IN (1,2,4) then 100 else 0 end)
    + max(CASE WHEN [code] IN (8) then 80 else 0 end)
  FROM 
    -- your table here
    (values (1, 'ali',4)
            ,(1, 'ali',1)
            ,(1, 'ali',8)
    ) as t(id, name,code)
  GROUP BY id, name;
```

**EDIT** another story for excluding something.
Any of 1,2,4 give 100 plus if it was only 4 without (1,2) add 400.

```
SELECT [id]
  ,[name]
  , r = max(CASE WHEN [code]  IN (1,2,4) then 100 else 0 end)
    + min(CASE WHEN [code]  IN (1,2) then 0 else 1 end) 
        * max(CASE WHEN [code]  IN (4) then 400 else 0 end)
    + max(CASE WHEN [code] IN (8) then 80 else 0 end)
  FROM 
    -- your table here
    (values (1, 'ali',4)
            ,(1, 'ali',1)
            ,(1, 'ali',8)
            ,(2, 'ali',4)
            ,(2, 'ali',8)
    ) as t(id, name,code)
  GROUP BY id, name;
```

**EDIT 2** If you need multiply scores, replace + with * and convert 0 into 1.

```
SELECT [id]
  ,[name]
  ,r = isnull(nullif(
        max(CASE WHEN [code]  IN (1,2,4) then 100 else 0 end)
      ,0),1)
    * isnull(nullif(
       min(CASE WHEN [code]  IN (1,2) then 0 else 1 end) 
        * max(CASE WHEN [code]  IN (4) then 400 else 0 end)
      ,0),1)
    * isnull(nullif(
        max(CASE WHEN [code] IN (8) then 80 else 0 end)
      ,0),1)
  FROM 
    -- your table here
    (values (1, 'ali',4)
            ,(1, 'ali',1)
            ,(1, 'ali',8)
            ,(2, 'ali',4)
            ,(2, 'ali',8)
    ) as t(id, name,code)
  GROUP BY id, name;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me if another customer only have code = 4 then I want to give him 500 points. I mean if he does not have code 1 and 2 but just code 4. What will be the query for it?Thank you

Comment: According to this query he will get 100 points even if he only have code 4 but I want to give him 500 points for only having code 4. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: What if he have 1,2 and 4? 100+ 500?

Comment: If he have 1,2 and 4 then it will be 100 but if he only have 4 then it will be 500.

Comment: if he have 1,2 and 4 then it will be 100 but if he have only 4 then it will be 500.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, It worked again but I just need a little more help. What if I want to multiply the points given to any customer like (100 * 80) . This time it should multiply the points not add them. Please help me with it too. I will be very thankful.

Comment: I tried by swaping * by + but it did not work. Please help me with it ince more. Thank you

Comment: Please help me with it. Thank you

Comment: When multiplying things "non-value" is 1 instead of 0. So besides replacing + with *  just wrap every former operand of addition with ISNULL(NULLIF(0,operand),1) to convert 0 into 1.

Comment: Please edit it in the 2nd answer you did as I am unable to understand it.

Comment: Please edit the answer to make it work as I have tried it but it failed.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I need your help once again sir with the actual data. Please see my edited query and sample data.

Comment: please help me once again. Thank you sir

Comment: Why is it returning 1 instead of 0.52. It should return 0.70 * 0.75 = 0.52? Can you please help me with it. Thank you

Comment: Please help me with it sir. I will be very thankful to you

Comment: Not sure about ORACLE casting rule, try  replace all  your integer   1 constants  with real ones    1.0

Comment: I have tried it but is didn't work. Actually when there is a case where anyone have code 1, 2,4 then it should multiply 0.70 * 0.20 but it is not multiplying them. The logic to handle case (1,2,4) is not working in oracle.

Comment: can you please convert your query in a way which is supported in oracle too?. If you can do it, I will be very thankful to you

Comment: If you can change your query by using COALESCE function rather then ISNULL, then it will be supported in both oracle and SQL server. Please help me with it. Thank you

Comment: Finally the question is a bit different from original one. :) I think further editing of the original answer will make it total nonsece, especially for other readers.  can you ask it as a separate question?

Comment: I have posted it as new question. Please help me there as you understand the whole process quite well. Here is the link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894752/i-need-help-converting-sql-query-to-oracle-supported-query". Thank you.

Comment: Please help me there

Comment: please help me with it

Answer (score 0):

You missed a comma (,) before the calculating the sum.

So your code should be:

```
SELECT [id]
  ,[name]
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN (SELECT [code] 
                   FROM [Test].[dbo].[testcode] as ts 
                   WHERE ts.id = t.id) IN (1,2,4) 
            then 100 
            else 10 
           end) as "total" 
  FROM [Test].[dbo].[testcode] as t 
  GROUP BY id, name
```

Answer (score 0):

You're **already** selecting from the `testcode` table - no need to do any subqueries in your `CASE` expression - just use this code:

```
SELECT 
    [id], [name],
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN [code] IN (1, 2, 4) 
               THEN 100 
           WHEN [code] = 8
               THEN 80
        END) AS [total] 
FROM 
    [Test].[dbo].[testcode] AS t 
GROUP BY 
    id, name
```